TypeORM migration not being created in the specified directory
I am using typeorm cli to generate migrations but the migrations are being created in the root directory as opposed to the directory specified in the configuration file. I have the following configuration file and npm scripts.
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import { config as dotenvConfig } from 'dotenv';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

dotenvConfig({ path: '.env' });

const config = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: `${process.env.DATABASE_HOST}`,
  port: `${process.env.DATABASE_PORT}`,
  username: `${process.env.DATABASE_USER}`,
  password: `${process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD}`,
  database: `${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}`,
  //   entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  entities: ['dist/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  //   migrations: ['../dist/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  // synchronize: true,
  migrationsTableName: 'typeorm_migrations',
  migrationsRun: true,
  logging: true,
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
};

export default registerAs('typeorm', () => config);
export const connectionSource = new DataSource(config as DataSourceOptions);


Scripts in package.json file:
"typeorm:cli": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -d ./src/config/typeorm.ts",
    "migration:run": "pnpm run typeorm:cli migration:run",
    "migration:generate": "pnpm run build && pnpm run typeorm:cli migration:generate src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:create": "pnpm run typeorm:cli migration:create",
    "migration:revert": "pnpm run typeorm:cli migration:revert"

I tried to run npm run migration:generate and it successfully generates the migration file but it is not generated in /src/migrations . Then running npm run migration:generate returns that there are no pending migrations to be run.

Did you use synchronize: true previously before generating the migrations

No. I turned synchronization off.

do you have a git repo for this code
